# Find $T(n)$ if for $T(n) = T(\frac {n - 1}2) + T(\frac {n - 2}2) + n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

> Find recurrence  $T(n) = T(\frac {n - 1}2) + T(\frac {n - 2}2) +n$

Usually for recurrences in the form of $T_n = T_{n-1} + T_{n-2}$, I use the characteristic polynomial, but I'm not sure if it works in this case.. and can't really use it.

Should I take 2 separate cases? for n even and n odd?

Comment: What is $\Theta(n)$?

Comment: some function of linear order

Comment: What do you mean by "finding recurrence"? Asymptotics? Can you already solve $T(n)=2T(n/2)+n$?

Comment: @md5 Yes, I can solve that, but how are those bounded? and also, on this principle on the example I gave with $T_n + T_{n-1} + T_{n-2}$ why doesn't it work the same approach?

Comment: @C.Cristi You can start with $M(n) = T(n)  - (2n+3)$. This will change your formula $M(n) = M(\frac{n-1}{2})+M(\frac{n-2}{2})$.

Comment: @DaniyarAubekerov Yeah, but that's kind of the part where I got stuck.